# Accessing Class Functions?

Tags: javascript, createjs

Can someone explain to me why I'm getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'canvas' of undefined game.js:48
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'resize' of undefined game.js:4

It appears that for some reason this.stage is outside of the scope of the start function.

```
//index.js
var game;
function init()
{
    game    = new Game(document.getElementById('canvas'));
}
function resize()
{
    game.resize();
}
```

_

```
//game.js
function Game(canvas)
{
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.stage  = null;
    this.loader = null;

    this.scaleCanvas();
    this.initCreateJS();
    this.loadAssets();
}

Game.prototype =
{
    resize: function()
    {
        this.scaleCanvas(this.canvas);
        this.level.resize(this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        this.stage.update();
    },
    scaleCanvas: function()
    {
        this.canvas.width   = window.innerWidth;
        this.canvas.height  = window.innerHeight;
    },
    initCreateJS: function()
    {
        this.stage  = new createjs.Stage(this.canvas);
        createjs.Ticker.setFPS(30);
        this.stage.enableMouseOver(10);
        if(createjs.Touch.isSupported())
        {
            createjs.Touch.enable(this.stage);
        }
    },
    loadAssets: function()
    {
        manifest = [
            {src:"base.png", id:"base"},
            {src:"logo.png", id:"logo"}
        ];

        this.loader = new Loader(manifest, this.start);
    },
    start: function()
    {
        this.level = new Level(4,4,this.stage.canvas.width,game.stage.canvas.height);
        this.level.randomLevel();
        this.level.print();

        game.stage.addChild(this.level);
        game.stage.update();
    }
};
```

Comment: How are you instanciating your object?

Comment: What's the client code (i.e., with `new Game()`)?

Comment: Where is the start method called?

Comment: Seems like this is in the scope of function, try Game.canvas, instead of this.canvas and so on.

Comment: Besides, I'm not quite sure I understand why use `game.stage` instead of `this.stage` in the ending lines of `start`.

Comment: @ronnyfm `Game.canvas` and `this.canvas` are two different properties.

Comment: That worked but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Why does using bind fix my issue?

Comment: What worked SyntheCypher?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
var Foo = function(val) {
  this.val = val;
}
Foo.prototype.log = function() {
  console.log('Me haz ' + this.val);
}
```

Here we defined quite a simple class `Foo`: with a constructor function assigning its param to a property named `val`, and a single method `log` working on this value defined on `Foo.prototype`. Nothing extraordinary:

```
var foo = new Foo(42);
foo.log(); // Me haz 42
```

Now we define a simple function - that takes another function as a param, and calls this function. Something like this:

```
var fooCaller = function(cb) { cb(); }
fooCaller(function() { 
  console.log('I am called'); 
});
```

That was easy, right. But now things suddenly become complicated:

```
fooCaller(foo.log); // Me haz undefined
```

What? Obviously the correct function has been called (hence `Me haz...`) - but why `this.val` is `undefined`, and not `42` there? What has changed between calling `foo.log` directly and via caller func?

The difference is `this`. See, a unique feature of JavaScript is ability to switch contexts (the objects referred by `this`) for the same function *without touching its body*: only the way of invoking the function matters. There are two special methods that allow you to explicitly set value of `this`: [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). For example:

```
var bar = new Foo(34);
bar.log(); // Me haz 34
bar.log.call(foo); // Me haz 42
```

As you see, with `call` I've switched `this` object from `bar` (which `val` property is equal to 34) to `foo`. Note that it doesn't matter anymore which object 'owns' the function.

---

Now let's get back to your own code. This line...

```
new Loader(manifest, this.start);
```

... is obviously buggy: passing unbound object methods as callbacks is almost always a bad idea. In this case Loader eventually calls the function stored in `this.start` - but when it will, `this` will point to another object.

To prevent this, you need to bind the context: pass into `new Loader` another function which is defined by the current value of `this`. The easiest way is to use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
new Loader(manifest, this.start.bind(this));
```

... which will basically create another function with fixed value of `this` (defined by its current value).

---

This, while quite extensive, is just a quick glance over how `this` functions in JavaScript (and not only in regards to functions, no pun intended )) ). I'd suggest checking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword) - and the articles mentioned in it, they sure will be quite enlightening. )